# Como ordenar consultas sql no model do RUBY on Rails?

Tags: sql, orientação-a-objetos, ruby-on-rails, classes

Tenho o seguinte método uma uma aplicação ROR.

```
query_student = "SELECT name, registration, room FROM students WHERE registration = "+
  params[:registration]+" AND password = "+params[:password]

  @student = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_student)
  render :json => @student
```

Porem me parece que na POO não seria legal manter a query na CONTROLLER.

Alguém sabe como eu poderia jogar essa consulta para model e apenas instanciar e tals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você tiver o modelo Students não precisa montar a sql

```rb
Students.where("registration = ?", params[:registration]).where("password = ?",params[:password]).order(:name)
```

Se você não tiver o modelo Students é melhor criar

```rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name="students"
    self.establish_connection :your_connection
end
```

Comment: Entendi, otmo, porem esse foi um exemplo tenho outras consultas que tiveram que ser personalizadas com sql puro mesmo, e gostaria de coloca-las no model e somente instancia-las...

Consultas que utilizo 3 JOINS e SUM

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma simples é utilizar o método "order" direto no controler.

Ex:

```
@users = User.order('name DESC').all
```

> No exemplo acima passamos uma query para o método order para listar todos os usuários por nome na ordem descrente.

Você também pode passar symbol, fica mais elegante, porém longe do ideal. Está é uma responsabilidade do model.

```
@users = User.order('name: :desc').all
```

[Aqui tem tudo que você precisa! =D   Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: nossa agradeço muito pela ajuda, mas realmente é esse o ponto, eu gostaria de jogar essa responsabilidade de consultas para o Model, como eu poderia tirar do controler e jogar para o MODEl ?

Answer (score 2):

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda, consegui jogar a responsabilidade do sql para o Model...

Criei um metodo no model

```
def sqlValidatedLogin(registration,password)
        query_student = "SELECT id, name, registration, room FROM students WHERE registration = "+
        registration+" AND password = "+password
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_student)
        end
```

e no controller , instanciei o objeto.

```
def index
  student = Student.new
  return_dados = student.sqlValidatedLogin(params[:registration].to_s,params[:password].to_s)
  render :json => return_dados
  end
```

tudo resolvido..vlw

Comment: Marque sua resposta como aceita para guiar outros usuários. :)